# Multiple eclipselink.left-join-fetch query hints

Tags: jpa, eclipselink

can multiple query hints with the same key be specified? Will it work? I need this to simulate entity graph which somehow doesn't want to work with Eclipselink scrollableCursor.
The problem is how to fetch 7 @OneToMany relationships in one query - multiple LEFT JOIN FETCH doesn't work either.

I would really appreciate any help.

Comment: What do you mean by the same key?  It doesn't make sense to use "Employee.phoneNumbers" in a query hint multiple times, but it might make sense to use it with "Employee.phoneNumbers.areaCode", and it will work.  But IMO its better to try it yourself and post your issues

Comment: I mean using multiple times the same hint key for example:
query.addQueryHint("eclipselink.left-join-fetch","customer.projects") and then another one query.addQueryHint("eclipselink.left-join-fetch","customer.items"). I have found one answer on stack where someone posted that they use hints like that and it works. I have checked it and it doesn't like why it would work in first place when hints are stored in HashMap so each key can be entered only once otherwise value will be replaced.